# use serialport to send multiple bytes (array) at a time

Tags: rust

The example code from serialport-rs documentation is as follows.

```
let output = "This is a test. This is only a test.".as_bytes();
port.write(output).expect("Write failed!");
```

Nevertheless, I want to send 64 bytes slices buffer like this,

```
 let buffer = &mut [0_u8; 64];  
 buffer [0] = 0xA6;
 buffer [1] = 0x55;
 port.write(&buffer[0..65]).expect("Write failed!");
```

The code below is what I just run for testing using fs::File.

```
use std::io::prelude::*;
use std::fs::File;

fn main() -> std::io::Result<()> {
    let mut buffert = File::create("foo.txt")?;
   
    let buffer = &mut [0_u8; 65];
    buffer [0] = 0xA6;
    buffer [1] = 0x55;
        

   buffert.write_all(&buffer[0..65])?;
    
    Ok(())
}
```

The input text in the file shows garbled text. Are there any other ways to achieve this?

Thank you!

The garbled text is something like this ��������������������������������������

Comment: It implements the [`Write` trait](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.Write.html). Do you know how to use that trait's [`write` method](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.Write.html#tymethod.write)? Start there, and make sure you first understand how to write your buffer to e.g. a file. Then writing to a `SerialPort` is no different.

And also: What's not working? What errors are you experiencing?

Comment: I just altered the code snippet. Thank you for the link.  I will look into it. What's not working is that the console on the recieving side shows a series of garbled characters.

Comment: I think I have problem switching between bytes array and string and that's where I get stuck...

Comment: What is the actual error? What is not working. Please describe that.

Comment: Btw: you can use `b"This is a test. This is only a test."` to generate a bytestring instead of calling `as_bytes` on your own.

Comment: Yes thanks. That's byte string but in my case I'd like to use byte array.

Comment: your slices are 65 bytes ,not 64 as you want to

Comment: Also your buffer is just zeroes. What do you expect to see ?

Comment: I did assign two values to the first two bytes. I suppose that I could expect to see two values followed by zeros at least.

Comment: On my PC I can see the `U`, but you cannot see the zeroes, as they are a *non printable character* thus the �. The `0xA6` is not a valid UTF-8 either, so whether you will see it depends on the configured encoding on your terminal/text editor

Comment: How silly I was... Thank you very much for your clarification!